# What is the algorithm to delete the dependencies of an InstanceGroup in the ibm cloud vpc

Tags: go, ibm-cloud, vpc

snippet:

```
service.DeleteInstanceGroup(service.NewDeleteInstanceGroupOptions(id))
```

Is failing.  The error message is `Delete locked, membership count must be 0 to delete InstanceGroup`

This is a true statement the membership count is 1.  It looks like the InstanceGroup dependencies need to be deleted before the instance group.

What is the algorithm to delete the dependencies of an InstanceGroup?

Comment: In the cli setting the membership count to zero seemed to help.  Still digging:  $ is instance-group-update r006-9d15bb49-0567-49b0-86ef-e444633c04db --membership-count=0

Answer (score 1):

For instance group to be deleted the membership count should be updated to zero, then wait for the instance group status to be healthy again and then delete the group.

The steps would be :

1. Check if instance group status is healthy, if not healthy then wait.
2. If healthy, then update the membership count to zero

```
    updateInstanceGroup := &vpcv1.UpdateInstanceGroupOptions{
        ID: &id,
    }
    zeroCount := int64(0)
    updateMemberShipCount := &vpcv1.InstanceGroupPatch{
        MembershipCount: &zeroCount,
    }
    memberShipCountPatch, _ := updateMemberShipCount.AsPatch()
    updateInstanceGroup.InstanceGroupPatch = memberShipCountPatch
    _, res, err := service.UpdateInstanceGroup(updateInstanceGroup)
```

3. wait for status to be healthy again
4. delete the group